# Showing True Type Font Personalized xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, ms-word, xslt-1.0

This is my xml:

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
      <IMMUTABLE_ID>9849</IMMUTABLE_ID>
      <LIGHT_STRUCTURE>
        <STRUCTURE_DESCRIPTION>Boa \A a fuso \B segnale \C speciale \D</STRUCTURE_DESCRIPTION>
      </LIGHT_STRUCTURE>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
```

Focus your attention on the fields "Structure Description":
You can see : "Boa \A a fuso \B segnale \C speciale \D"

in correspondence of the values \A,\B,\C,\D my xslt code open a true type font file and translate this \a or \b or \c or \d in a special different character.

My xslt code:

```
<xsl:template name="simboli">
<xsl:param name="testo"/>
<xsl:param name="separatore"/>
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($testo, $separatore)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($testo, $separatore)"/>
                <span style="font-family:lol;font-size:9pt;">
                    <xsl:value-of select= "substring(., string-length(substring-before($testo, $separatore)) +2, 1)"/>
                </span>             
                <xsl:call-template name="simboli">
                    <xsl:with-param name="testo" select="substring(substring-after($testo, $separatore), 2, string-length(substring-after($testo, $separatore)))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="separatore" select="$separatore"/>                        
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$testo"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You can see that I use font-family=lol <---custom font

```
<span style="font-family:lol;font-size:9pt;">
    <xsl:value-of select= "substring(., string-length(substring-before($testo, $separatore)) +2, 1)"/>
</span>
```

I open this XML file with Microsoft Word, I select Xslt file and after in output I get:

Boa A a fuso f segnale u speciale s

the letter f ,u and s should be a special character of LOL .

My question is:  Why converts only the first character?

N.B: I controlled XSLT and running correct, the only problem is that convert only the first \A and jumps \B \C \D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little bug in line

```
<xsl:value-of select= "substring(., string-length(substring-before($testo, $separatore)) +2, 1)"/>
```

Here you would like to output the beginning of the string up to the separator. You use the current context `.` to refer to the whole string. This works fine in the initial call to the template. When you recurse the `.` will still point to the *initial* string since apparently `<xsl:call-template>` does not change the context. Instead what you would like to do is take the substring of the string passed as `testo`:

```
<xsl:value-of select= "substring($testo, string-length(substring-before($testo, $separatore)) +2, 1)"/>
```

By the way: should it not be

```
<xsl:with-param name="testo" select="substring(substring-after($testo, $separatore), 2, string-length(substring-after($testo, $separatore)) - 1)"/>
```

to compute the length of the remaining substring? The version without the `-1` seems to work, though. :-)